# Add Labels to Admin Menu ( How To )

Tags: menus, admin, sub-menu, labels

I have a custom post type menu called "Notes". It has two basic sub menus: add new and show all.

But I want to add more items under these post type but the default array just gave me these. How can I add unlimited items?

I'm tired searching, but no result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, searching with the wrong keyword won't give you the right solution. It's a hint that you are dealing with the Admin menu, and anything under a menu drop-down is called a submenu - so you should search with something like: *How to add a submenu to any admin menu item + WordPress?*. :)

Anyways, adding an Unlimited submenu under a Custom Post Type would be a wrong approach - though you can (may) do it - but that would be irrelevant if that doesn't match with the purpose of that post type (CPT).

Now come to your question:

- Dealing with Administrative menus is documented in [this Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus).
- How to add a submenu is documented in [the Developer document](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/)

So in your case, the code can be:

```
<?php
function register_my_custom_submenu_page()
{
 add_submenu_page(
   'edit.php?post_type=notes', // parent menu slug
   'New Page Title',           // menu page title
   'New Menu Title',           // menu title
   'edit_posts',               // capability
   'new_menu_slug',            // menu slug/unique ID
   'submenu_callback'          // callback function
 );
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_submenu_page');

/* Callback Function */
/* It will be visible when you will click the submenu */
function submenu_callback() {
   echo '<h2>HERE IS WHAT MY PAGE IS ABOUT</h2>';
   echo '<p>Here is what my page says</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your great advices .. 
i have tired to search with to many word's ... your answer help me  thx again ...
 best regards ... 
so what if i want to show the content that exported from Note type post in the submenu page ??

Comment: :) That's a different question. Try more searching... :) and `$wpdb` or `WP_Query()` may help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
function my_cpt_extra_menus() {
    //Add Submenu Page
    add_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=my_cpt', 'Submenu Page Title', 'Menu Title', 'manage_options', 'slug_for_this_menu', 'function_to_output_html' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_cpt_extra_menus' );
```

Comment: thx v.match it's work :D